# Login method do not wait dispatch action finish before push route

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vue-router

In my component UserLogin, there is a submit button that call this method:

```
    methods: {
        login() {
          this.$store
            .dispatch("login", {
              email: this.email,
              password: this.password
            })
            //then redirect to default app
            .then(() => {
              console.log("2: router push to main")
              this.$router.push({ name: "main" })
            })
            //error handeling
            .catch(err => {
              this.error = err.response.data.error
            })
        }
      }
```

the login action dispatched is in my store module user.js

```
     actions: {
            login({
                commit
            }, credentials) {
                ChatService.userLogin(credentials)
                    .then(response => {
                        commit('SET_USER_DATA', response)
                        console.log('1 : login dispatch')
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('Error login:', error)
                    })
            }
        },
```

Chatservice is an axios api :

```
    import axios from 'axios'
    import store from "../../store/store"

    let apiClient = axios.create({
        baseURL: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`,
        withCredentials: false, 
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }) 

//The interceptor write the server token in Authorization header

    apiClient.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
        const token = store.getters.token;
        if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
            console.log(token)
        }
        return config;
    }, function (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });

    export default {
        // USER AUTHENTICATION
        userLogin(credentials) {
            return apiClient.post('/login', credentials)
        }
```

My problem is when i push submit button the 2 console log above are called in that order :

2: router push to main
1 : login dispatch

meaning the .then in my method is called before the action is finished. which is a big problem as it tries to push the route before I set userData information...

How can I change this behavior ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Your login action does not return anything, so there is nothing to wait for?

Comment: isn't the 
    userLogin(credentials) {
        return apiClient.post('/login', credentials)
    },
in my axios API that return something ? what shall i return then ?

Comment: OK actually i was ot watching the right thing. with your comment in head i re read the doc https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions and found where they return. I had to write written front ofChatService.userLogin(credentials) 
thanks for the tips !!!

Answer (score 0):

As @Samurai8 noticed i had to write a return,
so

```
return ChatService.userLogin(credentials)
```

fixed my problem.
found it in the doc of vuex actions https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. push the route in action like below

```
actions: {
            login({
                commit
            }, credentials) {
                ChatService.userLogin(credentials)
                    .then(response => {
                        commit('SET_USER_DATA', response)
                        console.log('1 : login dispatch')
                        this.$router.push({ name: "main" })
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('Error login:', error)
                    })
            }
        },
```

your login method will only dispatch the action and action will return promise..